# JSONField принимает любые значения от пользователя, что бы не ввёл - не только в формате json

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

Необходимо получить от пользователя данные в jsonB, затем вывести их на экран в формате json. Использовал в модели JSONField, однако принимает любые значения от пользователя, что бы не ввёл

models.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models

class UserForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    data = forms.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")     # получение значения поля name
        data = request.POST.get("data")     # получение значения поля data
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Name: {0}  JSON:{1}</h2>".format(data, name))
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
        return render(request, "index.html", {"form": userform})
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>User Forms</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def profile(request):
    data = {
        'name': 'Vitor',
        'location': 'Finland',
        'is_active': True,
        'count': 28
    }
    dump = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(dump, content_type='application/json')
```

Или так

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```